# Compute Engine start node server on instance startup

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, systemd

I am trying to run a discord bot in a node application in a free Compute Engine instance. I am struggling to make a script that actually starts the node app. 
I created this script and added it as `startup-script` metadata from file:
`cd code/movo-tron-2000 && npm start &`

I checked that the script runs with `sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup --debug`, but when I restart the instance, the app doesn't start. Running `sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service` prints the following logs:

```
Apr 20 12:19:08 bot-vm systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
Apr 20 12:19:09 bot-vm startup-script[691]: INFO Starting startup scripts.
Apr 20 12:19:09 bot-vm startup-script[691]: INFO Found startup-script in metadata.
Apr 20 12:19:09 bot-vm startup-script[691]: INFO startup-script: /startup-od52epug/tmpjy_z4vue: line 1: cd: code/mo
Apr 20 12:19:09 bot-vm startup-script[691]: INFO startup-script: Return code 0.
Apr 20 12:19:09 bot-vm startup-script[691]: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
Apr 20 12:19:09 bot-vm systemd[1]: Started Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts.
```

I see that the script gets executed, but also gets terminated. The app listened for requests, so it shouldn't get terminated in order to run. I assume that the startup script gets run on the same thread as the google compute engine startup script so it gets terminated in order to continue the vm boot. What should I change in my startup script in order to start my app properly and not have it terminated by the instance?

Edit: I set up the following systemd service and script at their corresponding locations

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start bot

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/me_adi_hf/code/movo-tron-2000/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

date > /root/bot_report.txt
du -sh /home/ >> /root/bot_report.txt
```

But when running `sudo systemd start bot.service` and then checking it's status with `sudo systemd status bot.service` am getting this output, indicating `Exec format error`:

```
bot-start.service - Start bot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bot-start.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-04-21 09:43:01 UTC; 9s ago
  Process: 19303 ExecStart=/home/me_adi_hf/code/movo-tron-2000/start.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 19303 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Apr 21 09:43:01 bot-vm systemd[1]: Started Start bot.
Apr 21 09:43:01 bot-vm systemd[19303]: bot-start.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/me_adi_hf/code/movo-tron-2000/start.sh: Exec format error
Apr 21 09:43:01 bot-vm systemd[1]: bot-start.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 21 09:43:01 bot-vm systemd[1]: bot-start.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 21 09:43:01 bot-vm systemd[1]: bot-start.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am not sure what causes the error, since the service file syntax looks correct

Comment: Top of my head I think you can control your service using SystemD. You only will need to create a [Service definition](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) and tell SystemD to be in charge of your service. Is there any restriction about using SystemD to control your applications?

Comment: Don't think so. Can you show me how to config it or point me to some guide?

Comment: First problem is that you are using a relative path `cd code/movo-tron-2000`. Use absolute paths.

Comment: If it were a problem it should have thrown a file not found error ,shouldn't it?

Comment: From my understanding, you startup script needs to be continually running. whereas, a compute engine startup script is meant to be executed at the boot phase and it will be terminated after its execution is completed. In your case, "startup-script: Return code 0" means that the startup script has been executed successfully. Therefore, the [startup script](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux) need to be run from the VM to meet your requirement.

Comment: Can you have a look over the edit please

Comment: Does the script has executable rights? Try `ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/me_adi_hf/code/movo-tron-2000/start.sh`